# Is it possible to compute factorials by converting to matrix multiplications?

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, factorial

An $n$-th term of the Fibonacci sequence can be computed by a nice trick by converting the recurrence relation in a [matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fibonacci_number&oldid=694204920#Matrix_form). Then we compute $M^n$ in $O(\log n)$ steps using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Would it be possible to use such a trick to compute factorials? If not, can it be proved? I figured out how to compute any polynomial in $n$ using this approach, but for factorials I wasn't able to express the factorial's recurrence relation as a linear transformation.

Comment: I guess the answer is no because if the norm of $M$ is $m$, then the norm of $M^n$ is at most $m^n$ whereas the factorial grows faster.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Good point, this deserves a proper answer to be voted for.

Comment: I have been far too often voted down for answering, and this one needs some minor(?) elaboration. Putting on an effort with a 50:50 probability to be collectively down-voted by some social communities here is not in the lines of my taste.  But I guess you have some input to answer the question for yourself, or some reputation hunter will take care of a proper answer. Edit: if you need some more input, dont hesitate to contact me.

Comment: @GyroGearloose That's sad to hear. Your argument seems to be an elegant proof why it can't be done, which I'd definitely consider as the accepted answer. From my point of view, what remains is to show that while all elements of $M^n$ are bound by $m^n$, it's not possible to somehow use them to compute the factorial. For example, one could then take two of the elements $u$ and $v$ and compute $u^v$, which would be larger than $m^n$. This would allow us easily to get to the magnitude of $n^n$, but it seems "obvious" factorial can't be expressed from a finite set of numbers like that.

Comment: (somehow the "@" does not work ...) Petr Pudlák, as far as I understand, your question is answered now completely and your understanding of it is as good as mine.  Let's that be fine for the two of us. If others do want more, just let them do.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: Re your latest comment -- that's quite interesting, I wonder how you could show that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fibonacci recurrence relation:

$$F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}$$

is linear. By that I mean it gives the next term as a linear combination of previous terms. Other recurrences having this feature are:

$$A_{n+1} = 3A_n + A_{n-1}$$
$$B_{n+1} = -4B_n$$
$$C_{n+1} = C_n + C_{n-1} + C_{n-2}$$

so any of those could be represented by matrices. Here they are!

$$
\begin{aligned}
M_A &= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}\\
M_B &= \begin{bmatrix}-4\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

And the last one is a challenge to the reader.

The Fibonacci matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

maps a vector

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_n\\F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}\\F_n\end{bmatrix}$$

and these work analogously.

But the factorial recurrence relation:

$$n! = n(n-1!)$$

is not a linear combination (with constant coefficients) of previous arguments, so we can't represent it as a matrix. That is, we can't represent it by the *same* matrix, no matter what $n$ we're trying to compute. When the coefficents are constant, we can, which lets us do exponentiation by squaring, etc.

Matrices are a convenient shorthand for representing **linear** functions on vectors. (They're not only a shorthand, but often I find it useful to think of them this way).

Comment: But by taking integer powers of Jordan-blocks you can have binomial coefficients which clearly are not linear.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: Hmm, can you give me a reference for what you're talking about? Sounds interesting. Note that I don't mean the function being computed grows linearly (Fibonacci numbers clearly don't) but just that the recurrence is linear. Binomial coefficients do have a linear recurrence $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$, which may be related to what you're talking about, but I'd have to see it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers

Comment: Well, the factorial recurrence relation is not linear with *constant coefficients*. The coefficient changes.

Comment: @Calle: Right, exactly. (I'll edit to make that more clear). If you represented it as a matrix, your matrix would constantly be having to change.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: That's really cool! Yeah, I would suspect that comes out of $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Looking at the link, it seems that the problem is that for a matrix of size $k$ you can only compute binomial coefficients of the form $n \choose i$ for $i\le k$, which (for a fixed $i$) can be expressed as polynomials of degree $i$.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I wouldn't call this a problem, just an inherent limitation ;-) . Which in turn could be used to proof that the answer to your original question is "No, because ... ".

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is probably not the answer you are looking for, but it might be interesting.

Let $D_k$ be the $k \times k$ matrix with zeros everywhere except on the superdiagonal, where it has the values $1, 2, \dots, k - 1$. Then the factorial $(k-1)!$ is equal to the first element in the vector
$$D_k^{k-1} e_k$$
where $e_k$ is the unit vector with a one at position $k$. Equivalently, the element at position $(1,k)$ in $D_k^{k-1}$ is $(k-1)!$.

### Example

$$D_5 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$D_5^4 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

### Explanation

The matrix $D_k$ acts on the space of polynomials of degree $\leq k$ as differentiation. Then one can use the following characterization of the factorial:
$$n!= \frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^n$$
and get the result above.

### Observations

The matrix $D_k$ can also be used to generate an upper triangular [Pascal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) $U_k$ through $U_k = e^{D_k}$, using the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

### A closer look at $D_k$

When you put $D_k$ on [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). For example with $D_5$ above you get $D_5 = S^{-1}JS$:

$$D_5 = \underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24
\end{array}
\right)}_{=S^{-1}}
\underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)}_{=J}
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{24}
\end{array}
\right)}_{=S}
$$
where $J$ is one big Jordan block (which is not surprising since $D_k$ is nilpotent), and $S^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix with factorials on the diagonal!

Investigating this a little but further reveals that this is not so strange. $D_k$ has only one eigenvalue, namely 0, with algebraic multiplity $k$ and geometric multiplicity 1. The eigenvector belonging to this eigenvalue is $e_1$.

When we put something on Jordan normal form, we use generalized eigenvectors, which are vectors $v$ that satisfy $(D_k - \lambda I)^n v = 0$ for some $k$. In our case $\lambda = 0$, so we just look at $D_k^n v = 0$. This gives us that $e_k$ is a generalized eigenvector. Remember our original formulation?
$$D_k^{k-1}e_k = (k-1)! e_1$$
which explains why we have factorials in $S^{-1}$.